# How to create a loop/skip in batch

Tags: loops, error-handling, batch-file

I am trying to download a chunk of files from an application. The shell command for it is 'go *filename* download'.

I have a text file containing all the filenames I have to download. All I want to do is to run a script/command such that when the above command is executed
1. the filenames are picked up from the textfile & executed using the above command
2. existing files/unavailable files are skipped
3. the process then continues with the next files in the list

So far I have this idea of using an operator like *go $ download* & then feed the operator with the text file containing the filenames list. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you can use `for /f` to process the file and create a command from it. The following script `supergo.cmd` shows how this can be done:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%f in (list.txt) do (
    echo go "%%f" download
)
endlocal
```

The following transcripts shows it in operation:

```
C:\Pax> type list.txt
file1.txt
file number 2.txt
another file.jpg

C:\Pax> supergo
go "file1.txt" download
go "file number 2.txt" download
go "another file.jpg" download
```

If you're using  a shell like `bash`, you can use `sed` to create a temporary script from the input file then run that:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -e "s/^/echo go '/" -e "s/$/' download/" list.txt >/tmp/tempexec.$$
chmod u+x /tmp/tempexec.$$
. /tmp/tempexec.$$
rm -rf /tmp/tempexec.$$
```

This puts an `echo go '` at the start of each line, a `' download` at the end, then marks it executable and executes it.

In both cases (Windows and `bash`), remove the `echo` to get it to do the real work.

Comment: how about in case a file is missing or has already been downloaded. How can I skip/handle such errors because last time I did something similar to what you said it terminated when it faced some problem.

Comment: @deppfx, I'd start with that script and get it working then ask for improvements. Since you don't _know_ whether the remote file is different from the local one, you'll have to download it just in case. Unless you can supply a way of checking, of course (checksums, sizes, etc).